# Is it possible to get comments without Post ID?

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-sdk-4.0

I am building an application where I'm using Facebook SDK. There is a scenario where I need to fetch the comments for a particular account using Graph API but the requirement is like that I don't have any post id for it. I have gone through the documents mentioned over developer.facebook.com and quite sure that without using Post ID we can't fetch comments. Still if anyone can help me with the same. Any help would be appreciable. Following is the link from where I read the document -

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v3.0/object/comments

Comment: Unless you had specific comment ids upfront (so you only want to read the data of comments you already know about), you will always have to go via the object the comment was made upon first. There is no way to fetch all comments made by a specific user.

Comment: @CBroe Thanks for the quick reply and as you mentioned in the last that "there is no way to fetch all comments made by a specific user", Is it the same if we want to fetch all the comments for a specific user ordered by timestamp?

Comment: There is no way, in any order.

Comment: Thanks for the time @CBroe